Are tensors only defined on a metric space?
I've been struggling to understand tensors for a long time and I think what really clicked for me is the idea that the length of a vector is invariant. Thus if you compute the length squared using the dot product,
$x^ix_i$
then $x^i$ and $x_i$ must transform in opposite ways under a change of coordinates in order for the result to stay the same.
The way they transform is determined by the metric tensor,
$x_j = g_{ij}x^i$
Thus it seems like the concept of a metric is fundamental to tensors and how they transform. Is this accurate? Is the way I understand tensors at least partly correct? Keep in mind I'm coming at this from more of a physics than pure math background.

You don’t mean a metric space. No, you can talk about vectors and tensors with no underlying inner product around. If you insist on raising/lowering indices, then you need some more structure.

@TedShifrin I thought the raising and lowering of indices, or I guess the different transformation properties of upper and lower indices, was what made a tensor a tensor and separated it from just a multidimensional array.

A matrix is a tensor, whether it represents a linear map or it represents a bilinear form. Tensors are defined — and have transformation rules — on differentiable manifolds, even if there is no underlying Riemannian or Lorentzian metric.

@TedShifrin The way I understood it is a tensor is something which transforms in a way that preserves the length of vectors, with 'length' being defined by a metric. Is that wrong?

Yes, it’s wrong. Even when a metric is present, tensors are far more general than that. Time to read some books …

@TedShifrin okay, just trying to understand, thanks!

No, the metric is not fundamental to how tensors transform. While historically all these notions might have been mixed up, now we know the distinction is very clear. Tensors are a purely algebraic device meant to capture some sort of multilinearity (a many-variable generalization of linearity).
If anything, what your reasoning points out is that (on a given vector space) there can be different types of tensors, i.e you’re sort of getting at the distinction between elements of $V$ (‘vectors’ or ‘$(1,0)$-tensors’) and elements of $V^*$ (‘covectors’ or ‘$(0,1)$-tensors’). And with ‘extra structure’ (namely a metric tensor) one can convert between these two different types.

As far as understanding tensors goes, you really should take the math route of learning linear and multilinear algebra proper; the physics route of introducing with coordinates and transformation laws takes much more effort to digest (even if it seems to have a lower barrier to entry when coming from a physics background). And as your question shows, it is very very easy to mix up various notions.
In linear algebra we have vector spaces. A natural question would then be “how can I make new vector spaces out of old ones”. Some common examples include:

Given two vector spaces $V,W$, we can always consider the space of all linear maps between them, $\text{Hom}(V,W)$.

If I only start with a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then keep in mind that we always have the underlying field $\Bbb{F}$, so we can apply the above constructions to get:

$\text{Hom}(\Bbb{F},V)$ … but this is isomorphic to $V$ in a natural way, so we didn’t ‘create’ anything new.
$\text{Hom}(V,\Bbb{F})$; this is by definition the dual space. This is a completely different beast.
applying duality again, we get $V^{**}$. It can be shown this is canonically isomorphic to $V$. So, we conclude that applying duality repeatedly doesn’t produce more examples.
But, we can still take $\text{Hom}$ spaces. For example, $\text{Hom}(V,V)$, or $\text{Hom}(V,V^*)$ or $\text{Hom}(V^*,V)$ or $\text{Hom}(V,\text{Hom}(V,V^*))$ etc.

The list goes on and on. These are all examples of vector spaces that can be produced just by starting with a single vector space $V$ and the underlying field $\Bbb{F}$, and the simple idea of ‘contructing all the linear maps between two vector spaces’. It turns out that we can organize all this information quite systematically if we introduce a ‘new’ construction; namely given $V,W$, there is some new vector space called $V\otimes W$ (and in the finite-dimensional case, this is actually canonically isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(V^*,W)$). So, all the Hom constructions I listed out in the last bullet point above are examples of this sort. They are respectively (canonically isomorphic to)
\begin{align}
V^*\otimes V,V^*\otimes V^*, V\otimes V,V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V^*.
\end{align}
So, essentially, if you keep applying the Hom construction, you’re going to end up with a vector space which is isomorphic to
\begin{align}
\underbrace{V\otimes\cdots\otimes V}_{\text{$r$ times}}\otimes \underbrace{V^*\otimes\cdots\otimes V^*}_{\text{$s$ times}}.
\end{align}
This is called the space of $(r,s)$-tensors on $V$.
This may seem very abstract, but it’s really just one idea, namely take the space of all linear maps between two vector spaces. Then, we take $V,\Bbb{F}$ and keep iterating this construction. So, in other words, if you understand what linearity means, then in principle you can figure out what a general tensor is.
Of course, in abstract algebra, people will introduce tensors slightly differently (see this answer), but at the end of the day, the whole purpose of tensors is to concisely capture the information within several vector spaces, all at once (‘in a multilinear fashion’).

Thank you! Some of this was hard for me to follow but it's a great starting point for looking into it further.
